# Unable to install Tensorflow with Python 3.8 in virtual environment

Tags: tensorflow, pip, virtualenv, python-3.8

On my Mac M1 (Monterey) I have created a new virtual environment with

```
virtualenv --python=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.8 ~/.virtualenvs/datascience_env
```

to link it with specific Python 3.8 version. Now I'm trying to install tensorflow. The following command (issued in the virtual environment):

```
(datascience_env)% pip install tensorflow
```

causes the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Just to be sure, I also did:

```
(datascience_env)% python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)" or python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P')*8)"
```

and the output confirms the 3.8 version:

```
3.8.14 (default, Sep  6 2022, 23:17:06) 
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally opted for a simpler solution. I followed [here](https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706) the procedure to install Tensorflow on Mac M1 with miniforge. Works like a charm. In summary the steps are [install miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge), then:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
conda create --name mytfenv python=3.8
conda activate mytfenv
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal
conda install -c conda-forge -y pandas jupyter
```